# Steam Update - Windows Games become unstartable

Tags: games, steam

So I am having this issue where everytime Steam updates, the games that are for Windows only that I could play before are no longer playebale. Cloud says the are up-to-date and the "Play" Button is green. But when I try to launch it, a small cloud icon with an exclamation mark appears right by the Game's name in the left sidebar of the library. Which takes me uninstalling steam, which takes ages, and the re-installing everything waiting for the next cycle to begin.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: The exclamation mark with the cloud icon just tells you that Cloud Sync is out-of-sync and has nothing to do directly with the game starting or not. But I have serious issues with Windows-only games since a couple of weeks too. You might want to add your system details and a list of games that do not start to your post.